# DDS QoS: Is it possible to send data without specifying a key?

Tags: c++, key, data-distribution-service, qos

I am currently using Eclipse Cyclone DDS C++ and I am wondering if it is possible to send data without any key specified with `#pragma keylist` in an IDL.

Is it possible to achive this through QoS-Settings? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `#pragma keylist TYPE` without listing any key fields, the IDL compiler will generate everything you need for creating a topic that doesn't have any key fields. So

```
struct S {
  long something;
  string orother;
};
#pragma keylist S
```

is perfectly valid, and then you can create a topic for `S`.

I am not entirely sure what you mean by

> In this case writes to the same topic could not be distinguished by the readers.

The above will result in a single instance for this topic. You can still have a history and so, e.g., the reader can still ensure it sees every update by specifying a `KEEP_ALL` history setting. The reader can therefore still distinguish between the writes by looking at the content and/or the sample info, but for DDS these are all updates to this one instance.

> Is it possible to achive this through the QoS-Settings?

No, you cannot (currently) override the key fields using the QoS settings.

Comment: I do not want to change the IDL file, therefore I can't add `#pragma keylist S' to it.

Comment: In that case, why not
```
     #include "S.idl"
     #pragma keylist S
```
?

Comment: That is almost what I did. I made a wrapper IDL-file with one key and the original file included. But I wondered if it is possible to transmit data without specifing a key.

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear. Thanks for your comments, that helped.